# Linq query that automatically excludes duplicates (one-liner)

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, query-optimization

I have a linq query for project euler problem 243:

```
var y = from n in factors
        from m in factors where m != n
        select n * m;
```

The problem is, for prime factors 2 and 3, it produces the y = {6, 6} where it needs to just be {6}.

Is there a way to do this without calling y.Distinct() or y.Contains() multiple times?

I also thought about using two foreach loops, but the problem is - I can't use indexing so it'd just be cumbersome and awkward.

Comment: Distinct would work. Why you do not want to use Distinct?

Comment: 1) it means I have to go through the the collection again, which can mean a lot if you're already nested in multiple loops.
2) general aesthetics :)

Comment: so you want 1 liner? like 
var y= ( from .... m).Distinct(); would also be a 1 liner.

Comment: Use `where m < n`.

Comment: @Rick *facepalm* - that's brilliant

Comment: Rick, you just made my night. It's people like you that make me realize there's still hope for us programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Rick Sladkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553613/rick-sladkey), changing

```
    from m in factors where m != n
```

to

```
    from m in factors where m < n
```

produces the correct result without having to use `.Distinct()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a distinct call on the resulting values. This way you don't have to do it on the inner loop.

```
var y = factors.SelectMany(n => factors.Where(m => n < m).Select(m => n * m)).Distinct();
```

If `factors = new[] { 2,3 }` you get `{ 6 }` as the result. Also if `factors = new[] { 2,3,4,6 }` you get `{ 6,8,12,18,24 }` instead of `{ 6,8,12,12,18,24 }`. Notice without the extra `12` in the result.